# Clash between glossaries-extra and enumitem package package?

Tags: fonts, enumitem, incompatibility, glossaries-extra

I am currently using `glossaries-extra` package for producing an acronyms list  in the `IEEEtran` class. However, when loading the `enumitem` package, the acronym entries suddenly turn **Bold**.

Here's the code to reproduce the issue?

```
\documentclass[nofonttune]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}  % <------ This package makes acronym entries BOLD!
\usepackage{microtype}

%%%%%%% glossaries ----------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[nomain, acronym, nonumberlist, nogroupskip]{glossaries-extra}

\setabbreviationstyle{long-short}
\renewcommand*{\glstextformat}[1]{\textcolor{black}{#1}} % link colouring to match normal text, ie black
\newacronym{adc}{ADC}{Analog to Digital Converter}
\newacronym{gigo}{GIGO}{Garbage In Garbage Out}

\setglossarypreamble[acronym]{\small}

\makeglossaries
%%% end of glossaries --------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
\title{Some bombastic title}
\author{John Doe}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Hello world. 
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
Intro

\glsaddall{}
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image: acronyms in bold]

When the `enumitem` package is commented out, we get

[image: standard acronyms]

Note that, in addition to being standard font, the acronym entry column is also in-flush (i.e. vertically aligned).

Is this a known incompatibility between `glossaries-extra` and `enumitem`? How do I restore the standard (i.e. non-bold) behaviour when using `enumitem`?

Comment: the clash is between the class and enumitem: the class redefines description, and enumitem overwrite this change. If you want to use enumitem you will have to setup the lists anew.

Answer (score 2):

`glossaries-extra` uses a `description` list by default to display the abbreviations and `enumitem` changes the default style of `description` lists. This is not an incompatibility per se (i.e. in functionality), only in default settings.

If you want non-bold labels, you can set `font` to `\normalfont`, for the alignment you desire, you have to set `labelwidth` to a sufficiently large value

```latex
\setlist[description]{font=\normalfont, labelwidth=3em}
```

either in your preamble (for the whole document) or before `\printglossaries`.